Segfault even though correct value in variable?
I have the following main.c:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

extern unsigned short addsub(int op1, int op2, char what, int *res, int *bit_count);

void print_flags(unsigned short flags) {
    printf("Flags:\n");
    printf("%s", "O D I T S Z   A   P   C\n");

    int bits_to_display = 12; // Significant bits only (0 included)

    for (int i = bits_to_display - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
        printf("%d ", (flags >> i) & 1);
    }
    printf("\n\n");
}

void print_result(int op1, int op2, int result, unsigned short flags, char operation, int bit_count) {
    // Signed interpretation
    printf("Ergebnis und Operanden Signed:\n");
    printf("%d %c %d = %d ", (signed char)op1, operation, (signed char)op2, (signed char)result);
    if ((flags & 0x0800) != 0) { // Overflow flag (OF)
        printf("(Ergebnis ist falsch!)\n");
    } else {
        printf("(Ergebnis ist richtig!)\n");
    }

    // Unsigned interpretation
    printf("\nErgebnis und Operanden Unsigned:\n");
    printf("%u %c %u = %u ", (unsigned char)op1, operation, (unsigned char)op2, (unsigned char)result);
    if ((flags & 0x0001) != 0) { // Carry flag (CF)
        printf("(Ergebnis ist falsch!)\n");
    } else {
        printf("(Ergebnis ist richtig!)\n");
    }

    // Print POPCNT result
    printf("\nDie Anzahl der gesetzten Bits im Ergebnis beträgt: %d\n", bit_count);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc != 4) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <operand1> <+|-> <operand2>\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    int op1 = atoi(argv[1]);
    int op2 = atoi(argv[3]);
    char op = argv[2][0];

    if (op != '+' && op != '-') {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Invalid operator. Use '+' or '-'.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    int res = 0;
    int bit_count = 0;
    unsigned short flags = addsub(op1, op2, op, &res, &bit_count);

    if (bit_count == -1) {
        printf("Diese CPU unterstützt den Befehl CPUID nicht!\n");
        return 1;
    } else if (bit_count == -2) {
        printf("Diese CPU unterstützt den Befehl POPCNT nicht!\n");
        return 1;
    }

    print_flags(flags);
    print_result(op1, op2, res, flags, op, bit_count);
    return 0;
}

which is combined with the following assembly module:
section .text
global addsub

; CPUID function genutzt um cpu informationen auszulesen

; EAX = 1 provides feature information in ECX
; Bit 23 of ECX = 1 indicates POPCNT support

addsub:
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp

    ; Load function arguments
    mov eax, [ebp+8]       ; Load op1
    mov ebx, [ebp+12]      ; Load op2
    mov ecx, [ebp+16]      ; Load operation ('+' or '-')
    mov edx, [ebp+20]      ; Load address of res
    mov esi, [ebp+24]      ; Load address of bit_count

    ; Save registers
    push eax
    push ebx
    push ecx
    push edx
    push esi

    ; CPUID for POPCNT support check
    pushfd
    pop eax
    mov ecx, eax
    xor eax, 0x00200000    ; Toggle ID bit in EFLAGS
    push eax               ; Save modified flags
    popfd                  ; Load modified flags
    pushfd                 ; Push modified flags to stack
    pop eax                ; Pop flags back into EAX
    xor eax, ecx           ; Check if ID bit was toggled
    jz no_cpuid            ; CPUID not supported

    ; CPUID supported, check POPCNT support (bit 23)
    mov eax, 1             ; Set EAX to 1 (feature information)
    cpuid
    test ecx, 1 << 23
    jz no_popcnt           ; POPCNT not supported

    ; Restore registers
    pop esi
    pop edx
    pop ecx
    pop ebx
    pop eax

    cmp cl, '+'
    je add
    cmp cl, '-'
    je sub

    ; Invalid operation
    xor eax, eax
    leave
    ret

add:
    add al, bl
    mov [edx], eax         ; Store result
    pushfd
    pop eax
    jmp count_bits

sub:
    sub al, bl
    mov [edx], eax         ; Store result
    pushfd
    pop eax
    jmp count_bits

count_bits:
    push ebx
    push esi
    mov ebx, [edx]
    and ebx, 0xFF        ; Hardcoded 8-bit limit
    popcnt ecx, ebx        ; Count the number of set bits in result
    mov [esi], ecx         ; Store bit count in variable
    pop ebx
    pop esi
    jmp fin

no_cpuid:
    mov dword [esi], -1             ; CPUID not supported flag for C program
    jmp fin

no_popcnt:
    mov dword [esi], -2             ; POPCNT not supported flag for C program
    jmp fin

fin:
    leave                  ; Restore stack frame (includes pop ebp)
    ret 

The purpose of the program is to read the flags of the CPU and return them. When I try to read the flags variable after the addsub() method finishes the program crashes, and I can't find why. In gdb the correct value is stored in the flags variable. When I remove the print statement the program works as expected.
Maybe someone can help because I am going insane!

Aside: why the casts in printf("%d %c %d = %d ", (signed char)op1, operation, (signed char)op2, (signed char)result);?

The asm code says "restore registers"  before the ret but these are not the original values.

@burneraccount, Please add the arguments used for main().

A sample execution would be: ./program 1 + 1

The addsub prototype is at the top of the c code, which is then implemented in assembly

I see that now.

Calling convention mandates some registers be preserved, including ebx and esi. You don't do that. Also you tagged x86-64 but this is 32 bit code.

@Jester I got a tip that my code violated 32bit-x86 calling conventions. So I need to preserve abx and esi?

Yes, you should do that. Since you already push and pop them a little reordering should take care of the problem.

@Jester Where would I place the push statements. Can I just pop them before leave is called?

Yes and you should push them in the prologue. If you change your argument loading you don't even need to bother with the remaining registers.

Also note your invalid operation case does not leave.

@Jester I have update the code with some potantial imprvement but still no dice. Could you maybe try it on you machine?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

I suspect the issue is because you do not preserve the registers as per calling convention. I rearranged your code a little which should fix the problem:
global addsub

; CPUID function genutzt um cpu informationen auszulesen

; EAX = 1 provides feature information in ECX
; Bit 23 of ECX = 1 indicates POPCNT support

addsub:
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp
    ; Save registers
    push ebx
    push esi
    mov esi, [ebp+24]      ; Load address of bit_count

    ; CPUID for POPCNT support check
    pushfd
    pop eax
    mov ecx, eax
    xor eax, 0x00200000    ; Toggle ID bit in EFLAGS
    push eax               ; Save modified flags
    popfd                  ; Load modified flags
    pushfd                 ; Push modified flags to stack
    pop eax                ; Pop flags back into EAX
    xor eax, ecx           ; Check if ID bit was toggled
    jz no_cpuid            ; CPUID not supported

    ; CPUID supported, check POPCNT support (bit 23)
    mov eax, 1             ; Set EAX to 1 (feature information)
    cpuid
    test ecx, 1 << 23
    jz no_popcnt           ; POPCNT not supported

    ; Load rest of function arguments
    mov eax, [ebp+8]       ; Load op1
    mov ebx, [ebp+12]      ; Load op2
    mov ecx, [ebp+16]      ; Load operation ('+' or '-')
    mov edx, [ebp+20]      ; Load address of res

    cmp cl, '+'
    je add
    cmp cl, '-'
    je sub

    ; Invalid operation
    xor eax, eax
    jmp fin

add:
    add al, bl
    mov [edx], eax         ; Store result
    pushfd
    pop eax
    jmp count_bits

sub:
    sub al, bl
    mov [edx], eax         ; Store result
    pushfd
    pop eax
    jmp count_bits

count_bits:
    mov ebx, [edx]
    and ebx, 0xFF        ; Hardcoded 8-bit limit
    popcnt ecx, ebx        ; Count the number of set bits in result
    mov [esi], ecx         ; Store bit count in variable
    jmp fin

no_cpuid:
    mov dword [esi], -1             ; CPUID not supported flag for C program
    jmp fin

no_popcnt:
    mov dword [esi], -2             ; POPCNT not supported flag for C program

fin:
    pop esi
    pop ebx
    leave                  ; Restore stack frame (includes pop ebp)
    ret

